# My own OrderBy function

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am writing a piece of code which is going to order the list of photos based on their rating. Each photo is stored in DB, and each has such information as number of positive and negative votes. I want to order them by the formula in which I count the percentage of positive votes, and the first photo is the one with the highest percentage.

For that I used the standard IComparer interface, and wrote my own Comparer function, which compares two photos. The problem is that I do that I have to first download the list of all photos from the db. It seems like a lot of unnecessary effort which I would like to avoid. So I am wondering if it is possible to create my own SQL function which will do the comparing on the DB side, and returns to me just the photos I want? It is more efficient than comparing all the photos on the server side?

The code for my own comparer:

```
public class PictureComparer : IComparer<Picture>
{
    public int Compare(Picture p1, Picture p2)
    {
        double firstPictureScore = (((double)p1.PositiveVotes/(double)(p1.PositiveVotes+p1.NegativeVotes))*100);
        double secondPictureScore = (((double)p2.PositiveVotes / (double)(p2.PositiveVotes + p2.NegativeVotes)) * 100);
        if (firstPictureScore < secondPictureScore) return 1;
        if (firstPictureScore > secondPictureScore) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And the code which uses the comaprer:

```
 var pictures = db.Pictures.Include(q => q.Tags).Include(q => q.User).ToList();
 pictures = pictures.OrderBy(q => q, new PictureComparer()).Skip(0 * 10).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: just before thinking of an answer to your question, in your method PictureComparer.Compare() you can forget the  * 100 when you compute firstPictureScore and secondPictureScore. It doesn't change anything in the comparison

Comment: Any reason you can't code up a stored procedure that will only return the wanted records and call it from EF?

Comment: and what do you mean by "the photos I want"? The first X ones?

Comment: @PierrOz, yeah you are right, I can omit the "*100", and by the first X photos, I mean that i use the ".Skip(0 * 10).Take(10)" functions to take only 10 photos from the selected position in the list, that's why I don't want to download all photos from the DB and than sort them.

Comment: @Oded, probably I can, but that's not something I have ever done, that's why I am asking for the best solution of such a scenario, the one being most efficient and easiest to produce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the first call to `ToList` and use a lambda expression instead of defining a comparer:

```
var result = db.Pictures
    .Include(q => q.Tags)
    .Include(q => q.User)
    .OrderByDescending(q => 
         q.PositiveVotes + q.NegativeVotes == 0
             ? -1
             : q.PositiveVotes / (double)(q.PositiveVotes + q.NegativeVotes))
    .Skip(n * 10)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. It looks like a great piece of code, and as far as I understand the sorting is done on the DB side right? But I have one problem with that code, I don't want to exclude the elements which have 0 positive or negative votes, I just want them at the end of the list, is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The calculations in your comparer code are independent (i.e. the comparison just depends on ordering a value that can be calculated without reference to the item you are comparing to).  Therefore you should calculate your positive percentage number first and just use the calculated value in your comparer.

This should certainly be done in the database if possible (i.e. if you have access to make changes to the database).  Databases are suited to this kind of calculation and you could probably do it on the fly without having to cache the calculated values, by which I mean have a view that works out the percentage for you rather than precalculating and storing the value everytime there is a positive or negative vote.  This will obviate the need to download all the photos to compare, as you can just order by the positive percentage.  Below is some sample sql that will do the job (note it is only a sample...you might want to store the vote as a bit or something more efficient).  The votes table contains a list of all votes for a particular picture and who voted for it.

```
declare @votes table(
pictureId int,
voterId int,
vote int)

insert into @votes select 1,1,1
insert into @votes select 1,2,-1
insert into @votes select 1,3,1
insert into @votes select 1,4,1
insert into @votes select 2,1,-1
insert into @votes select 2,2,-1
insert into @votes select 2,3,1
insert into @votes select 2,4,1

declare @votesView table(
pictureId int,
positiveVotes int,
NegativeVotes int)

insert into @votesView
select pictureId, sum(case when vote > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as PositiveVotes, 
SUM(case when vote < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NegativeVotes from @votes group by pictureId

select pictureId, convert(decimal(6,2),positiveVotes) / convert(decimal(6,2), (positiveVotes + negativeVotes)) as rating from @votesView
```

Comment: Nice, so as far as I understand it will be better to store the "positivePercentage" value at all times, and calculate it at the point of adding the new vote?

Comment: That is one way, but probably not required.  Just have a view that maintains the calculations.  The simplest way would be to create two views...the first sums up the positive and negative votes (as per the second last select statement in my code above) and the second view references this view and works out the percentage value (as per the last select statement above).  This way you don't need to do anything when someone votes as the views will always be up to date.